# Is it possible to have multiple values in a cell

Tags: macos, numbers

I have a Column called "Genre" where it should be different TV show genres, but as you all might know these could be multiple. Like Drama, Comedy and so forth.

When filtering for Comedy I need to select "Comedy" as well as "Comedy, Drama" and so on. Is it somehow possible to add multiple genres within a cell?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So you can use countif() like so:

[image]

```
COUNTIF(B$3:B$5,"*"&D2&"*")
```

Made a very simple set of data as you did not provide much. The genres can be separated by commas as shown or spaces or semi-colons etc

Shown in Numbers as well:

[image]